# Azure OAuth token failure with ADFS on internal network

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, token, adfs

We have a Windows 10 UWP application getting oauth tokens from Azure AD. The code to request a token is pretty simple.

```
var _authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/azuread.microsoftonline.com");
var result = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(  "key",  "key","http://redirurl", PromptBehavior.Auto);
```

On a azure subscription with ADFS enabled, a domain user will get redirected to the ADFS credential page when they enter in their corporate credentials. They will then authenticate and be issued a token without issue. When we try the same behavior on a machine on the internal company network, it appears the ADFS server tries to redirect somewhere for a Kerberos ticket or NTLM authentication. The user/pass dialog times out and gives us a message that it can't connect right now. This works like a champ on every network we have tested expect the internal corporate network.

All this happens within the single call to AcquireTokenAsync. It feels like we have a configuration problem but I am not sure where to start. We have some traces where it appears that WIA is not being handled correctly but I am not sure where we might have a config problem.

Thanks for any help, this is driving us crazy...

Comment: Trying to understand. Are you saying that the pattern works if your client is outside the network, but fails if it is inside the network? What version of ADFS is this? Windows clients traditionally can do seamless windows integrated auth from a domain joined machine and ADFS is optimized for this. So, your reasons could be one of the following... (1/2)

Comment: (1) Your client machine is not domain joined to your AD, (2) Your client machine is not configured to do WIA over a web request. To do this, add your ADFS hostname to the intranet zone on your machine through IE settings (3) Your ADFS is not configured to handle WIA correctly based on user-agent-string.

Comment: Yes to your first question. Not sure what version of ADFS, but think you are right on the money with suggestion number two. We are seeing the ADFS server request the WIA, but nothing after that. Thanks very much for these ideas, 2 or 3 sounds like our issue.